# How can I add a pandas column with a current month offset?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a calendar table in Pandas with several columns like date, year, month and I'd like to add a new column with the current month offset of the date in another column. E.g. for the date 2021-02-01 I'd like to have the current month offset of -1 and for 2021-04-01 an offset of +1.

Here is how the Calendar table looks right now:

[image]

Here is what I'd like to have:

[image]

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Does `df['Date'].dt.month - pd.Timestamp.today().month` work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subtract months periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2021-05-01', freq='MS')})

now = pd.to_datetime('now').to_period('m').ordinal
df['MonthOffset'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('m').astype('int') - now
print (df)
         Date  MonthOffset
0  2020-01-01          -14
1  2020-02-01          -13
2  2020-03-01          -12
3  2020-04-01          -11
4  2020-05-01          -10
5  2020-06-01           -9
6  2020-07-01           -8
7  2020-08-01           -7
8  2020-09-01           -6
9  2020-10-01           -5
10 2020-11-01           -4
11 2020-12-01           -3
12 2021-01-01           -2
13 2021-02-01           -1
14 2021-03-01            0
15 2021-04-01            1
16 2021-05-01            2
```

Answer (score 0):

This will add a column, MonthOffset, to the dataframe with the offset to the current month.

```
df['MonthOffset'] = df['MonthNumber'] - datetime.today().month
```

Comment: The other answers are more appropriate as they don't require any further imports - mine requires importing datetime from datetime.